# Changing background color of textfield depending on value entered

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Good day! I just want to ask if its possible to change the background color of a UITextField depending the value entered on it? Or can I set the values for any specific color?
e.g. I set 5,10,15,20 red and 3,6,9,12 green? I tried this code but only for a single color, I want to change to depending on the value I entered,

```
 case 0:
        yy = self.txtTimestamp.frame.origin.y + self.txtTime.frame.size.height;
        self.txtTimestamp.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        break;
case 1:
        yy = self.txtTrucknumber.frame.origin.y + self.txtDrivername.frame.size.height;
        //self.txtDrivername.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        break;
case 2:
        yy = self.txtDrivername.frame.origin.y + self.txtClockin.frame.size.height;
        //self.txtClockin.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        break;
case 3:
        yy = self.txtSsn.frame.origin.y - self.txtTrucknumber.frame.size.height;
        //self.txtTrucknumber.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        break;
case 4:
        yy = self.txtClockin.frame.origin.y - self.txtTrucknumber.frame.size.height;
        //self.txtTrucknumber.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        break;
```

Comment: yes, you can do it. but you need to store all the values first then just use conditions for entered value.

Comment: can you provide a good sample for it? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you mind (and if it respects your requirements), you could replace your UITextField with UITextView, and use the delegate method :

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
```

So you can change the background color of `textView` depending of its property `textView.text`. 
For custom colors, use :

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:<#(CGFloat)#> green:<#(CGFloat)#> blue:<#(CGFloat)#> alpha:<#(CGFloat)#>]
```